# Can't cast IQueryable<Tobject> to Tobject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code

```
var contact = repository.GetContacts.Where(p => p.ID == id);
repository.DeleteContact(contact);
```

the variable "contact" is of type `IQueryable<Contact>`, the `DeleteContact()` method takes a Contact object.

How can I cast/convert contact from `IQueryable<Contact>` into `Contact`?

Comment: `contact` isn't a _single_ contact. It is a collection of them - so `contacts` would be a better name. Now, think about how to get the `First` (or `FirstOrDefault`) of those contacts.

Comment: it is a collection that only has one contact

Comment: **You** know that. The **compiler** and **runtime** doesn't know that (there is only one). An egg container with a single egg in it is still an egg container - not an egg. Thus `contacts` is a better name until you `FirstOrDefault` it to get the `contact`.

Comment: If your are sure about the result return just one object (record) you can use Single instead Where (Or SingleOrDefault Or First and FirstOrDefault)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `Where` clause is returning an `IQueryable<Contact>` (a collection of contacts), not a single contact (even though the collection may have only one item in it).

The two options that come to mind are either delete **all** of the contacts:

```
foreach (var contact in repository.GetContacts.Where(p => p.ID == id).ToList())
{
    repository.DeleteContact(contact);
}
```

Or if you only expect one or none, you can use `SingleOrDefault` to get a single contact:

```
var contact = repository.GetContacts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);

// If it's not null, delete it
if (contact != null) repository.DeleteContact(contact);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList()` just for a `foreach`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto habit because we're deleting items from the collection inside the loop